# In linq.js in need a query for list inside list

Tags: json, linq.js

I am having a list like:

```
var a=[   
  {col1:"a", list:[{subCol:"s1"},{subCol:"s2"}]},   
  {col1:"b", list:[{subCol:"s1"},{subCol:"s2"}]}
]
```

Here am having list inside list. For this I want a query like enter code here

`linq(a).where("$.col1=='a' && $.list.subCol=='s1'")`

I tried this syntax but gives empty list as output. Is  this  correct?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

`list` is an array of objects.  I suppose you're trying to check if any item in the list has a `subCol` `s1`.  You'd have to check the items.

```
var query = Enumerable.From(a)
    .Where("$.col1 === 'a'")
    .Where("Enumerable.From($.list).Any(\"$.subCol === 's1'\")")
    .ToArray();
```